# How to sum digits recursively javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm learning the basics of JavaScript and am trying to write a recursive function to add together a group of integers.  For example, the function argument would be `1234` and the result should be `10`.  Here's what I have so far...

```
function sumDigits(numbersStr) {

  var numToString = numbersStr.toString()
  var numArr = numToString.split('').map(Number);

  var sum = 0;

  // base case
  if (numArr.length === 0) {
    return sum
  } 

  // recursive case
  else {
    var popped = numArr.pop();
    sum+=popped;
    return sumDigits(numArr);

  }
}
```

But I get an infinite loop whenever I run this (my tab crashes).  If I'm popping the last element of an array, adding it to the `sum` variable, then calling the function again on the shortened array, then why do I get an infinite loop?  Many thanks!

Comment: And  what did you try to debug?did you try to `alert` some values

Comment: `console.log` is a preferred means of debugging code.  Or, use a breakpoint and step through line by line.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense; `sumDigits` doesn't take an array. If you want to use an array you need a function that takes an array and an accumulator.

Comment: Definitely a lack of debugging...

Comment: I suggest you rename your argument.  `num` implies a variable that contains a *single number*.  It should be `numbersStr` or something else.

Comment: @Amy `1234` *is* a single number; it's only later that it's conflated with an array of numbers, which also wouldn't be `numbersStr` :/

Comment: I suggest start by describing the solution in words: "The sum of digits of a number is the sum of (what?) and the sum of the digits of (some smaller number). Can you fill in the details that go in the parentheses?

Comment: I tried to console.log `numArr.length` & `popped` in the else block to see if it was actually getting shorter but my browser window keeps crashing

Comment: @Amy This is completely doable with a number.

Comment: You're right.  I misread the code, thought he was splitting a string containing numbers separated by apostrophes.

Comment: Note that you do not need to convert the number to a string. You can do this entirely with arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that sumDigits expects to get a number, but in the recursion you pass an array of numbers to it.

Comment: Not the only problem, but a start.

Comment: ^^ This answer.  I didn't realize I was passing an array into the recursive function when I should be passing something like `numArr.join('') * 1)`

Comment: @e1v1s You *could* do that, but that's a lot of unnecessary conversion back and forth.

Comment: What do you _suggest_ I do ( I dont want to be 'spoon fed' ) ?

Comment: Various things. For example, don't convert the string to an array at all, but use substr to manipulate the string - remove the last character, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a string or number as argument of the function and convert the value to a string.

Then check the length and return zero if the length is zero (usualy the exit condition).

If not return the value of the fist character and add  the result of calling the function with a sliced string from index one.

Basically a recurisve function have two parts.

1. The exit condition with an exit value. This depends on the purpose of the recursive function. It is usually a neutral value, like zero for addition, or `1` for multiplication.
2. The actuall value plue a arithmetic operation and the call of the function again with a reduced string/array or numerical value.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
    num = num.toString();
    return num.length === 0
        ? 0
        : +num[0] + sumDigits(num.slice(1));   
}

console.log(sumDigits(1234));
```

Another approach would be the use of [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), which does not extend the stack for each calling function, because the function ends with the call without keeping a temporary value liek in above function, the actual numerical value `+num[0]` and the waiting for execution of the adition.

In this case, you could store the intermediate result along with the calling of the function.

```js
function sumDigits(num, sum) { // num is expected to be a string
    sum = sum || 0;
    if (num.length === 0) {
        return sum;
    }
    return sumDigits(num.slice(1), sum + +num[0]);
}

console.log(sumDigits('1234'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function digitCount(num) {
     let val1 = num % 10
let rem = Math.floor(num / 10)
return val1 + (rem != 0 ? digitCount(rem) : 0)
}

console.log(digitCount(87))
```

Comment: Note, "and am trying to write a recursive function" in the questions.  This feels more like an exercise in learning recursion than an open question on summing digits.

Comment: pls check again

Comment: Much better, although note that the name is misleading, as it *sums* or *totals* the digits, and doesn't *count* them.

Comment: Note that this technique is in other answers as well, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/48894103, and also note that it can be expressed as a one-liner like `const digitSum = (n) => n <= 0 ? 0 : n % 10 + digitSum (Math.floor (n / 10))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function takes a number as it's argument, but when you use it recursively, you're giving it an array back. I would recommend pulling the recursive part into its own helper function like so:

```js
function sumDigits(num) {

  var numStr = num.toString()
  var numArr = numStr.split('').map(Number);

  function sumHelper(arr) {
    // Base case:
    if (arr.length === 1) {
      return arr[0];
    }

    // Otherwise recurse (return last number plus the sum
    // of the remainder):
    return arr.pop() + sumHelper(arr);
  }

  // Then use that recursive helper:
  return sumHelper(numArr);
}

console.log(sumDigits(1234))
```

Comment: @DaveNewton I merely answered that which was asked. I'd like to improve the answer, but what should I have done instead?

Comment: IMO only it's better to nudge people towards discovering the solution on their own when it's clearly either an assignment or self-study problem. That's just me, YMMV.

Comment: Up to you--it' just one approach to handling questions. Until they're about to smash their heads I prefer having people pursue the answer(s) on their own ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: @CRice That's just Dave's opinion. Don't let that throw you off. There's nothing at all wrong about your approach. Others would remind Dave that Stack Overflow isn't just about the OP getting their answer, it's also a knowledge base for folks in the future that have a similar issue. When answers are only partial or hints, it doesn't serve the community at large.

Comment: Although the QA format of stackoverflow probably isn't conducive to a more "hinty" type of answer, I could have only minimally modified OPs original code to get it working. I guess I don't really know where the best answer would have been in the range between a full-fledged solution or just hints as to what was going wrong, but thanks to both of you for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects a string, but on the recursive call, you pass it an array.

Additionally, you've got a call to `.map` that isn't needed because you can convert the strings in the `.split` array to numbers simply by prepending a `+` to them.

Is there any reason you just don't use `Array.reduce`?

```js
function sumDigits(stringOfNums) {
  // Split the string into an array of strings. Reduce the array to the sum by 
  // converting each string to a number.
  console.log(stringOfNums.split('').reduce(function(x,y){ return +x + +y}, 0));
}
sumDigits("1234");
```

Comment: @Barmar Answer updated to explain problem with original code.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's the best decision you've made all day, I'm sure.

Comment: Ooo, now insults. Good one!

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array in the recursive call will guarantee that its `.toString()` will never be empty because the commas will add more characters than have been removed.

Instead, do it mathematically so you don't need an array or even string conversion.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  return num ? (num%10) + sumDigits(Math.floor(num/10)) : 0
}

console.log(sumDigits(1234))
```

This assumes a positive integer is passed. You'll need additional guards if other input could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert the number to an array. You can get the last digit of a number with `number % 10`, and remove that digit with `Math.floor(number / 10)`. Then recurse until the number is `0`.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  if (num == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var last = num % 10;
    var rest = Math.floor(num / 10);
    return last + sumDigits(rest);
  }
}
console.log(sumDigits(1234));
```

Answer (score 0):

Barmar has a good voice of reason. Converting from number to string then converting back to number again is a bit silly. Plus, if this is a homework assignment, using high-level functions like `String.prototype.split` probably won't teach you much.

Here's a tail-recursive version Barmar's program written using functional style

- base case - the input number `n` is zero, return the accumulator `acc`
- inductive case - `n` is *not* zero; recur with the next `n` and the next `acc`

```js
const sumDigits = (n = 0, acc = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? acc
    : sumDigits (n / 10 >> 0, acc + n % 10)

console.log (sumDigits ())     // 0
console.log (sumDigits (1))    // 1
console.log (sumDigits (12))   // 3
console.log (sumDigits (123))  // 6
console.log (sumDigits (1234)) // 10
```